# Subset of stabiliser is a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Definition:
>   Let G be a permutation group of a finite set $\Omega.$
>
> Let $\alpha \in \Omega.$
>
> The Stabiliser of the point element $\alpha$ in the group G is the set 
>   $G_{\alpha}=\left \{ g \in G\mid \alpha^{g}=\alpha \right \}$

Some issues with showing inverse of an element in G is in $G_{\alpha}.$

Here's my attempt:

Assume $g=e \in G_{\alpha} \exists g \in G_{\alpha}. $

Then, by definition, $\alpha^{e}=\alpha.$

Indeed, $[e \in G_{\alpha}] \wedge [G_{\alpha}\neq \varnothing ]$

Now, suppose $g, h \in G_{\alpha}.$
Then, $\alpha^{g}=\alpha $ and $ \alpha^{h}=\alpha$

Composing the two above,

$\alpha^{g\ast h}=\alpha^{h} = \alpha$

we have closure.

To show inverse:

$e=g^{-1}\ast g$

$\alpha^{e}$=$\alpha^{g^{-1}\ast g}$

Would like for a useful hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Assume so..." *what*? Your third line below the yellow parraph.

Comment: Edited. @Joanpemo Careless typo

Comment: Thank you, yet I still cannot understand that $\;\exists\;$ there : you wrote: "Assume g equals e in $\;G_\alpha$, exists g in $\;G_\alpha;$" ...perhaps you meant $\;g=e\implies g\in G_\alpha\;?$

Answer (score 1):

$$g\in G_\alpha\implies \alpha^g=\alpha\implies \left(\alpha^g\right)^{g^{-1}}=\alpha^{g^{-1}}$$

But we know that one of the axioms of action of group on set is $\;(\alpha^g)^x=\alpha^{gx}\;,\;\;\forall\,g,x\in G\;$, so continuing where we left above:

$$\alpha^{g^{-1}}=\alpha^gg^{-1}=\alpha^1=\alpha\implies g^{_1}\in G_\alpha$$

and we've finished.